# @Path annotation not working while creating a RESTful webservice

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I am creating a simple RESTful webservice using jaxrs version 2.23.2. But @Path not working.
Service Class

```
package com;

import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/User/Services")
public class UserServices {
    @PUT
    @Path("/create")
    public void createUser(){
        System.out.println("Inside createUser");
    }
    @GET
    public void getUser(){
        System.out.println("Inside getUser");
    }   
    @POST
    public void updateUser(){
        System.out.println("Inside updateUser");
    }
    @DELETE
    public void deleteUser(){
        System.out.println("Inside deleteUser");
    }
}
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>RestFullTest</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myrest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>    
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myrest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

After creating this, if i am giving /User/Services in the browser URL, nothing is getting printed in the console.
eg :

```
http://localhost:8089/RestFullTest/rest/User/Services
```

Comment: Which method you want to call? '/User/Services' mentioned in class level, what about method level?

Comment: I want to call getUser() method.

Comment: use something like `@Path("/getuser")` in `getUser()` method level and your should be something like `http://localhost:8089/RestFullTest/rest/User/Services/getuser` . By the way why the return type is void while you want to get something from the method?

Comment: I want to simply check whether the control is going in that method or not. There is a createUser method with the path ("/create").
So by giving the path
`http://localhost:8089/RestFullTest/rest/User/Services/create`
nothing is printed on console and control is not going in that method.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println()` method prints on the server side, so the text will not be sent over to client as you expected. To see the message as text in the web browser you need to return a String as a response:

```
@GET
public String getUser(){
   return "Inside getUser";
}
```

You can find a simple rest example here (go to 6.3. Java Class section):
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html

Comment: It should print in the console. But nothing is printed in console

Comment: You need to register your REST servlet package with Jersey Servlet container  in web.xml `<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myrest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>`

Comment: You think my solution solved the problem. Please upvote.

Comment: http://localhost:8089/RestFullTest/rest/User/Services/ for getUser method yaa by adding the above code in web.xml its solved